# Every time show error message when redeemRewards function call in branch.io

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I am developing an iPhone application with integrating Branch.io in which i am using Referrals functionality. According to Referrals Documentation i've done almost all steps. when i m trying to load rewards and  redeem rewards then error message print: **You're trying to redeem more credits than are available. Have you loaded rewards?**.

Please Suggest me how to load rewards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewards are added when users complete the condition setup on the referral rule that you have created. For example: if you have set up a rule to award all acting users 10 credits every time they trigger the event 'signup'. Then 10 reward credits will be added to both referring and referred user when the referred user signs up. You can then redeem these rewards. 
Alternatively, if you would like to add rewards to a specific user you can use the API call to do so https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/#referral-reward